# Overriding Methods in Multi-level Inheritence

Tags: c#

Given three parent/child classes, like this:

```
class A {
    public virtual void doSomething() {
        //do things
    }
}

class B : A {
    public override /*virtual?*/ void doSomething() {
        //do things
        base.doSomething();
    }
}

class C : B {
    public override void doSomething() {
        //do things
        base.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Should class `B`'s `doSomething()` method have both `override` and `virtual` in its signature, since it also is overridden by the `C` class, or should only class `A` have `virtual` in its `doSomething()` method signature?

Comment: That's odd. It doesn't complain at all for me.

Comment: I just made those classes in the question form, as an example. But no, it does not complain if I mark a method as override and virtual. Perhaps that's a feature of Visual Studio 2012 or 2013? I'm using 2010 for school.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to (read: you can't) mark a method as virtual, if it has already been marked as virtual in one of the super classes.

The method will remain virtual throughout the inheritance tree until a subclass marks it as `sealed`. A sealed method cannot then be overridden by any of the subclasses.

Answer (score 6):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3.aspx):

> You cannot use the **new**, **static**, or **virtual** modifiers to
>   modify an override method.

Also,

> The overridden base method must be **virtual**, **abstract**, or **override**.

Meaning that you *can* override a method that is already marked as override.